# GitHub: Privileges

Tags: git, github

I'm new to GitHub (and Git in general) and we've decided to use it for a software development class. We have 3 teams working on 3 different 'game types' in the application. None of the features are interconnected, but each use the base framework. What is the best way to create a repo for this?

I was thinking the following:

1. Have a main fork, which contains the base framework.
2. Create 3 forks, one for each team.

However, I don't want each team to be able to edit the base framework. They should not have permission to do so. But they should be able to sync with it, if it changes.

I've Googled permissions on GitHub and I can't seem to find restrictions outside of the "Corporations" feature, which I don't know if I should use -- should I?

If not, should I create another account, one per team, and they issue a pull request to copy to their own repo, and change that? Is that a valid solution?

Comment: I don't really use git, but here is one idea: since none of your 3 'forks' are ever going to be merged, either with each other or with the base framework, would it not be best to create one repositry for your base framework and then get each team to clone (not sure if this is the right term) the base repository and edit from their own respositries?

Comment: Well, I may have misspoke. It IS going to become one project in the end, but there will just be a selection screen to specify which mode you want to play. So ultimately, it will all be together.

Comment: @Derek: That's what submodules are for. You can have separate repositories integrated in one bigger project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an organization, with the framework and each project in its own repository. Use git submodules in each project (or your programming language's package installer.. like RubyGems/Bundler if you're using Ruby, for example) to pull in the framework. Create teams for each project in the organization and assign each team read access to the framework and committer access to that team's project.